# React Native Нажатие на SVG в react-native-svg-pan-zoom

Tags: svg, react-native

Есть задача нарисовать SVG, больше чем экран, т.е. с функцией Zoom/Scale. А так же необходима возможность нажать на какую либо часть картинки и соответственно получить от этого нажатия эффект (пусть хотя бы console.log).
С прорисовкой справляется svguri, а с масштабированием react-native-svg-pan-zoom, но от туда не пробивается ни один onClick или onPress:
Беру код из примера один в один: https://github.com/garblovians/react-native-svg-pan-zoom.

И onZoom из SvgPanZoom даёт сигнал. А вот ни один OnClick/onDrag из SvgPanZoomElement уже не отвечает. Пробовал заворачивать свг в TouchableHighlight, не помогает, пробовал рисовать кнопку TouchableHighlight рядом(но внутри тега SvgPanZoomElement), тоже не даёт эффекта.

Кто знает подскажите как получить onpress или onclick? Или как решить иначе можно?

---

Компонент PinchZoomView пропускает onPress от TouchableHighlight.